# JavaScript Coercion: Console vs Script

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements, coercion

today, I encountered something rather strange. Consider the following code (which I use to sync a range slider with an input element):

```
// val = "50"
// other_val = 100  
if( val > other_val ){
    console.log(val + '>' + other_val); // => 50 > 100
    console.log( val > other_val); // => true
    $input_max.val( other_val );
}
```

How did that happen? When I type

```
"50" > 100
```

into my console (Chrome & FireFox), it says false, which is what I expected. I fixed the resulting bug with **parseInt()**, but I still don't know *why* this happened. Also, I don't know why I can't reproduce it outside of this script.

Any ideas? :)

Cheers!

**Update:**

As Bergi pointed out, it was **"50">"100"**, and not **"50" > 100**. Thank you very much for that idea. Now, my real question seems to be:

Why does this return true:

```
"50">"100" // => true
```

Comment: You want to know why `val + '>' + other_val` resulted `"50 > 100"` ?

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown not what OP is asking....

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown Looks like OP wants to know, why `"50">100` logs `true` from a script, but `false` when you run it directly in the console.

Comment: it can never happen. `"50"` is converted to `50` and `50 > 100` results in `false`, so the if block is never executed.

Comment: It was. That's the trouble I'm having with this. Has to be something else. But what?

Comment: Are you sure that it's not `"100"` instead of `100`? Because `"50" > "100"`.

Comment: @Bergi Maybe that's it. I'm gonna check. Thanks!

Comment: So why is "50" > "100"?

Edit: Oh, of course, it's a string compare sorting by character. And '5' > '1'.

Comment: @Bergi: Exactly. Thanks. So "50">"100" does not behave as I expected either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your edited question is that when you compare strings it compares character by character from the beginning of the string. And the character 5 is "larger" than 1.

Comment: Tested it, "50">"100" returns true, "050">"100" returns false. Thanks, mate!